# complicated integration problem

Tags: integration

Last question.

Consider the area between the graphs $x+ 4y = 26$ and $x + 6 = y^2$. This area can be computed in two different ways using integrals

First of all it can be computed as a sum of two integrals
$\int_a^b f(x)dx + \int_b^c g(x)dx$

where a =  , b =  , c =  and 
f(x) =
g(x) =

Alternatively this area can be computed as a single integral
$\int_{\alpha}^{\beta} h(y)dy$
where $\alpha$ =  , $\beta$ =  and 
h(y) =
Either way we find that the area is  .

I don't understand how this is possible

Answer (score 1):

The two curves described by the equation are a line with shallow negative slope and a "horizontal parabola" with its vertex at (-6, 0).  Here is a graph of the region in question bounded by these curves:

[image]

If we integrate in the $ \ x-$ direction, we have to deal with a change in the boundaries.  Starting at $ \ (-6, 0) \ , $ we are integrating between the two "arms" of the parabola, given by the positive and negative square-roots, $ \ y = \pm \sqrt{x+6} \ . $  At the first intersection point and continuing to the second one, the "upper curve" becomes the line, while the "lower curve" continues to be the "negative arm" of the parabola.

When we instead integrate in the $ \ y-$ direction, the curve "further" from the $ \ y-$ axis, which would be the "upper curve", is *always* the straight line, so the "lower curve" is always the parabola.  Here, we need to express both curves using functions of $ \ y \ $ (whereas the parabola is *not* a single function of $ \ x \ , $ which is why we use the two square-roots individually for the " $x-$ integration").

You will find that for the integration problems you will be facing that involve "area between curves", volumes of solids of revolutions, arclengths, surface areas of solids of revolutions, and so on, it is valuable to have a graph or a sketch of a graph of the situation called for.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I always recommend sketching the area. Once you've done this it should be easy to "see" where you get these integrals from.

Once sketched, you will see that the area is bounded by three curves. You will also see that the line intersects the parabola at two locations. for the seeming arbitrary numbers below, you will need to find the points of intersection.

The singley written double integral can be see as bound by $\{-6\leq{x}\leq{26-4y},-8\leq{y}\leq{4}\}$

The doubly written double integral can be seen as two pieces. The first piece is bound by $\{-\sqrt{(x+6)}\leq{y}\leq{\frac{26-x}{4}},10\leq{x}\leq58\}$ and the second $\{0\leq{y}\leq{\sqrt{(x+6)}},-6\leq{x}\leq10\}$

If you are having trouble graphing the area by hand, use an online tool like [this one](http://my.hrw.com/math06_07/nsmedia/tools/Graph_Calculator/graphCalc.html). some programs don't like you to enter functions as $y^2$, so you'll need to split it up. In this case, plot $y=\frac{26-x}{4}$, $y=\sqrt{x+6}$, and $y=-\sqrt{x+6}$.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the picture: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%2B4y%3D26%2C+x%2B6%3Dy%5E2

in the first case you are integrating with respect to $x$:

$f(x)=\sqrt{x+6}-(-\sqrt{x+6})$ $g(x)=13/2-x/4-(-\sqrt{x+6})$

in the second case you are integrating with respect to $y$ (just looking at the functions from the $y$ axis):

$h(y)=26-4y-(y^2-6)$

Answer (score 0):

You can see the region here: [graphing calculator](http://www.emathhelp.net/calculators/calculus-1/online-graphing-calculator/#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)

Curves intersect at two points.

Find points of intersection by solving system $x+4y=26, x+6=y^2$.

Solution is (10,4) and (58, -8).

If you want to integrate with respect to x, then you will have two integrals and you need to express all functions in terms of x:
$y=\sqrt{x+6}, y=-\sqrt{x+6}, y=\frac{26-x}{4}$.

First integral: $\int_{-6}^{10}(\sqrt{x+6}-(-\sqrt{x+6}))dx$

Second integral: $\int_{10}^{58}(\frac{26-x}{4}-(-\sqrt{x+6}))dx$

Things are easier if you want to integrate with respect to y.

Rewrite functions in terms of y:

$x=y^2-6, x=26-4y$

Integral: $\int_{-8}^{4}((26-4y)-(y^2-6))dy$